# RobotFramework expected arguments

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to run some test with Robot Framework, but when I try this code I get the following error

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Suite Setup     Go to homepage
Suite Teardown     Close All Browsers

*** Variables *** 
${HOMEPAGE}          http://www.google.com
${BROWSER}           chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Google mdh and find mdh.se
           Google and check results    mdh    www.mdh.se

*** Keywords ***
Google and check results
         [Arguments]     ${accept}    ${searchkey}   ${result}
          
      
         Click Button class=RveJvd snByac   ${accept}  
         Click Button    name=btnK   ${searchkey}
         Wait Until Page Contains    ${result}

Go to homepage
       Open Browser           ${HOMEPAGE}          ${BROWSER}
```

Keyword 'Google and check results' expected 3 arguments, got 2.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, you are not passing the `${result}` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass one more argument to your keyword "Google and check results". It required totally 3 and ${result} argument is missed here.